# Declaring and later defining an array in C

Tags: c

Edit: I would like to ask the question differently;

Why would this produce a compile time error:

```
int a[];

int main(){
    a[] = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

How else can it be done? Above works if `a[] = {1, 2, 3};` is defined globally like this:

```
int a[];
a[] = {1, 2, 3};

int main(){
    //
}
```

Old question:

Assume the following:

test1.h

```
void init();
int a[];
```

test1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test1.h"

int a[] = {6};
int main()
{
    init();
    return 0;
}
```

test2.c

```
#include "test1.h"

void init()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("%d\n", a[0]);
}
```

Above will have this compile time error:
`error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'int []'`

However, `printf("%d\n", a[0]);` will print `6` just fine. Why `sizeof` cannot be used with 
this way of declaring arrays?

Comment: Accessing an array element doesn't require knowing the size of the array. Array access is just pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Aside: `printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));` is better done with a matching specifier: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof a);`

Comment: At file scope, in C89  `a[] = {1, 2, 3};` was allowed and equivalent to `int a[] = {1, 2, 3};`. The C89 language allowed you to leave the type name out of a declaration and `int` was assumed if so.  This is not allowed since C99 but compilers might offer it as an extension, you should see a warning if you compile in conforming mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Why would this produce a compile time error:*

The compiler needs to know how much memory to reserve for an array in static storage at compile time, so it can't depend on code in functions.

> *Why sizeof cannot be used with this way of declaring arrays?*

First of all, `int a[];` should be `extern int a[];` in `test1.h`.

The size of the array is set by `int a[] = {6};`, which is found in a file compiled completely independently, and thus not available when requested by `sizeof`.

The size isn't needed for `a[0]` since no bound checks are performed.

Comment: Why don't I have to use `extern` when dealing with a regular variable like `int a`. I tried and it worked without it.
Also why would `a[] = {1, 2, 3};` work globally? I edited my question above to add an example.

Comment: Both `int a;` and `int a[];` work without `extern` with my `gcc`. I can't tell you why they work without `extern`. But it's far clearer if you use it where appropriate.

Comment: if it's working globally then why won't work in a function? because compiler needs to know how much memory to reserve and it can't do it when defining within a function?

Comment: Re "*if it's working globally then why won't work in a function?*", This is answered by my answer.

Comment: Also I though `extern` is an alternative to `define in a header and include the header where needed`, it's not use both `header ` and `extern`, one should  do it, no?

Comment: Thanks, now only If I could get the difference between `extern` and `define in a header`.

Comment: "why won't work in a function" is answered by my answer. As for why `a[] = {1, 2, 3};` works, why wouldn't it?

Comment: `extern` is a C keyword. `define in a header` is not valid C.

Comment: Sorry, tired. Earlier deleted comment was correct. It said: `a[] = {1, 2, 3};` is short for `int a[] = {1, 2, 3};`. Enable and use your compiler's warnings. (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`.)